# Getting '#default_value' from $form

Tags: forms

I have this code:

```
$form['custom'] = array(
'#title' => t('Some title'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => $custom,
'#default_value' => isset($option->name) ? $option->name_id : '',
'#description' => t('Some text goes here.'),
```

Now when i do print_r i get data from option and the name_id of the selected one.
No how can i get this data (name_id) from "#default_value" ??

In submit function i have this:

```
$custom=$form_state['values']['custom'];
```

But this only gets me the name not the name_id .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the form itself:

```
$custom = $form['custom']['#default_value'];
```

Comment: O thank a million , my brain frozen i couldnt think any more. I done it before but just couldn't think it. You the man :).